# qq Fileuploader always shows " Upload failed " in IE9

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, nopcommerce

I am a beginner in qqFileuploader. I use qq File uploader in my MVC3 application

Uploader works fine in the Firefox and Chrome but it's always shows the " Failed " message

in the IE 9. Please see my image

[image]

I am clueless. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue just recently.

The issue stemmed from the fact that it wasn't getting the JSON it was looking for - I had set the content type to return, and that was what actually messed it up.

I had this line in VB.net:
`context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"`

Once I removed it, the issue went away. Just make sure that you're doing the correct formatting of the JSON that you're returning. I assume you are since it's working in Firefox and Chrome, but for some reason IE was thinking it was XML even though I was specifically telling it that it should be JSON.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!
My fix was to change from $_GET["qqfile"] to $_FILES["qqfile"] in my php file. I only this this fix for IE9. And my script also upload only 1 file.